# Alternative of httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments to check more than one path segments at a time

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

My Code

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISecretKeyModel SecretKeyModel)
        {
            if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
            {
                if (httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("SecretKey", out StringValues SecretKey))
                {
                    SecretKeyModel.SecretKey = SecretKey.SingleOrDefault();
                    if (SecretKeyModel.SecretKey.Equals(_config.Value.ClientSecretKey)) SecretKeyModel.IsValid = true;

                }
            }
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
```

In the above code, I have checked whether the path string segment start with "/api" or not.
But, I want to check more than one or group of such paths, I can do like this

```
if(httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") || httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/app"))
```

But i want another methods to do this

Answer (score 3):

You could put all values that you need to check in a list or array then use linq `Any()` method:

```
var list = new List<string> { "/api", "/app" };

if (list.Any(s => httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(s)))
{
    ...
}
```